# How have Multiple consoles running in eclipse or netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I would like to know how to run two or more different classes within the same package in an Eclipse or Netbeans IDE. I know it's possible but I can not find the how. That is, for example, I have a class with the typical example of "Hello World", which prints in a loop to infinity and then I have in another class a calculator that adds numbers entered by the user, but when giving it to execute, do not stop to execute none and keep the two running.

Comment: Why Eclipse and Netbeans? This would be easy in IntelliJ or the console.

Comment: @John I prefer to use IDE's, I do not care which one, if one or the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse, navigate to "New Console View" - > https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uEi0.jpg
You can drag and reposition wherever you please.

Comment: that's what I needed, but I do not know why it shows me the same execution and not different

Comment: A project will only have one Console. If you want two that run seperate tasks you will need to create an individual project for each. After doing that, on one of your Console Views, you can select the "Display Selected Console" button which is next to the "New Console View" and select the other project in order to view them both.

Comment: The latter if it has served me more or less the Display Selected Console and see the console at a certain time. To be more exact I was making an echo application, with a client and a server. The client creates data and the server replicates it. But with this last, more or less if it helps and serves me. Thank you very much.